# MYSQL select candidate rows randomly but only once

Tags: android, mysql, sql, select, random

I have a table in my database which has 3 columns: `id`, `name`, `category_id` which has 1 million rows. the user selects a `category_id` in the app and then the database has to return 12 rows which have the selected category_id. then in the next api call, the database has to return the next 12 rows which have the selected category_id and so on.

My question is how I can return the rows randomly and **avoid returning repeated rows in next api calls**?

Comment: What do you mean by "...next 12 rows"? I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding here: table rows do not have inherent row ordering. You'll need to be more specific.

Comment: @TheImpaler by `next` I mean 12 `other` rows which have the selected `category_id` and have not already been returned by the api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a repeatable random sort. For this you can use `RAND()` with a seed. The idea is that each search should be assigned a constant seed (that you can persist in the user's session, for example).

Assuming that a user has seed `12345`, you can fetch its first page like:

```
select * from mytable where category_id = ? order by rand(12345) limit 12
```

Then the second page is fetched as follows:

```
select * from mytable where category_id = ? order by rand(12345) limit 12, 12
```

Third page:

```
select * from mytable where category_id = ? order by rand(12345) limit 24, 12
```

And so on.

Comment: Respectfully, I don't think this solution will work. It assumes the engine processes/reads the rows in the same order always, and that's not a given.

Comment: @TheImpaler: as far as I understand [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand), this should do it.. See the example given with `RAND(3)`.

Comment: No, no... I agree with the `RAND()` function. That's good. The problem resides in the row retrieval by the engine. It's not stable in time. Today it may retrieve row 1, then 5, then 2, but tomorrow it could retrieve 2, then 1, then 5.

Comment: @TheImpaler so the RAND() function with the same seed returns different results each time?

Comment: On the contrary, it does return the same values each time. What's not assured is to which rows those values will be *assigned*.

Comment: @TheImpaler: ok, so we agree on the behavior. Now, as I understand the question, that's exactly what OP wants: a repeatable random sort, over which they can paginate.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `id` is a key of the table and has positive values only, you can do:

```
select id, name, category_id
from my_table
where category_id = ? and id > ?
order by id
limit 12
```

The first time you call it, you can use:

- category_id = `123`
- id = `-1`

The second time you get the max `id` from before (let's say `25`) and use that one.

- category_id = `123`
- id = `25`

Comment: nice solution, but there is no randomness included in these queries. they read the database from the top to the bottom

Comment: You can add randomness by storing a value in the table (extra column), or by doing it on the fly. You probably want the latter since it provides per-session/user randomness; for a million rows this will be expensive, though. Your queries will be slow. If you store the random value (and update it once in a while) the queries can still be somewhat random, but on the plus side will be instantaneous. It's a compromise I don't know you are willing to accept, though.

Comment: you mean to use a random value as the cursor of the database (id value)?